# How do you mathematically define a random line or in general, a random subspace of a Euclidean space?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-graphs, random-matrices, geometric-probability

I'm looking for a definition of random $k$-dimensional vector subspace of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d, k, d$ are fixed. I'm guessing one should start with a random basis, i.e. a set of independent random vectors $\{X_1 \dots X_k\} \in \mathbb{R}^d,$ and then use some kind of quotienting argument. But this is where I'm having a bit of problem: using the quotient construction.

EDIT I: (after seeing the first four comments): So, upon a second thought, it seems to me that one can think of a random subspace as a random variable (i.e. a measurable function $X$) that takes values in the Grassmanian manifold $Gr(d,k), X: \Omega \to Gr(d,k), 1 \le k \le d,$ of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^d.$ So in particular, a random line would be a random variable/measure function $X: \Omega \to Gr(d,1) = RP^{d}.$

EDIT II: As mentioned in some of the comments, I need some kind of uniformity to define such a random subspace. Perhaps this is basic, but I'm not sure I completely understand what problem I'd run into if I want $X$ to be non-uniform? I mean for a general Riemannian manifold, non-uniform random variables exist...

I'd appreciate a rigorous definition or a reference here.

P.S. If we can start with a random line for now to keep things simple, that'd also be great!

Comment: If you just take a set of random vectors in $\mathbb R^d$, you'll run into the problem that you will have to use some kind of non-uniform distribution. Instead, you could choose a set of random vectors on the unit sphere $S^{d-1}$, which is compact and thus allows a uniform distribution. You don't even have to restrict them to be independent, since the dependent sets should be a zero-set in the associated probability space.

Comment: "Random" isn't meaningful without a distribution. Based on your description, I guess you are in fact interested in a somewhat "uniform" distribution. There is a natural choice: view the Grassmanian variety as a homogeneous space (in face a quotient) over $\operatorname{GL}$ and take the invariant measure (sometimes also called the Haar measure). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure for details.

Comment: If the space in question does not have a finite Haar measure one can still construct a Poisson process whose intensity measure is the Haar measure.

Comment: Look up integral geometry and kinematic measure.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thank you for your comment, but I think I'm not sure I know what problem I'd run into if I choose a non-uniform distribution (I modified the question accordingly). Also, I think instead of $D^{d-1},$ we want $RP^d:= S^{d-1}/\{\pm 1 \}$ if we're considering the random lines, which are one dim subspaces of $R^d, $ hence elements of the Grassmanian $Gr(1,d).$

Comment: @WhatsUp Thank you for your comment! Yes indeed upon a second thought, I updated the question with the Grassmanians. So yes, I think I'm looking for measurable functions $X: \Omega \to Gr(k,d). $ But as Vercassivelaunos mentioned as well, I'm not sure I completely understand why we must've:  $f_X \equiv 1 \iff X$ is uniform? What's wrong with $X$ being non-uniform?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with non-uniform random variables. I just assumed that you wanted your subspace to be chosen uniformly, so it would be easier to handle if the basis vectors could be generated uniformly. But it's not technically necessary. Also, it doesn't matter wether you choose a distribution on the sphere or projective space. You'd choose $k$ elements anyway, and then take the span (of points on the sphere) or their sum (of lines through the origin from projective space). The resulting distribution on the Grassmannian should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I will extend my comment above.

What you need is a probability measure $\mu$ on the Grassmannian $Gr(d, k)$ (endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). It is then meaningful to talk about the probability of your random subspace lying in a given open subset of the Grassmannian.

The natural choice is to view the Grassmannian as a quotient $\operatorname{GL}_d(\Bbb K)/P_{d - k, k}$, where $\Bbb K$ is your coefficient field (i.e. $\Bbb K = \Bbb R$ if you only consider real vector spaces), and $P_{d - k, k}$ is the parabolic subgroup consisting of all block upper-triangular matrices with block sizes $d - k$ and $k$ on the diagonal, i.e. $$P_{d - k, k} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\0 & D\end{pmatrix}:A\in\operatorname{GL}_{d - k}(\Bbb K), D \in \operatorname{GL}_k(\Bbb K)\right\}.$$

You would naturally want to define a $\operatorname{GL}_d(\Bbb K)$-invariant measure on this quotient. However, there is no such a measure, because $\operatorname{GL}_d(\Bbb K)$ is unimodular, while the parabolic subgroup $P_{d - k, k}$ isn't. (It is possible, in this case, to define a "twisted" version of Haar measure, but you will not be able to integrate it against a function on the Grassmannian, so it's not useful to us.)

However, in the case $\Bbb K = \Bbb R$, there is a way to overcome this. The point is that requiring it to be $\operatorname{GL}_d$-invariant is perhaps too strong and unnecessary. Instead, we can use Iwasawa decomposition to rewrite the Grassmannian as $O_d(\Bbb R)/(O_{d - k}(\Bbb R) \times O_k(\Bbb R))$. Now every group is compact and hence unimodular, so we may define a Haar measure on this quotient. It is $O_d(\Bbb R)$-invariant.

It should be easy to extend this method to other local fields, e.g. $\Bbb K = \Bbb C$ or $\Bbb Q_p$ or $\Bbb F_p(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's still no answer, I'll give it a try. This might not be the most elegant method to construct what you want, but at least it's something. User WhatsUp's idea with the Haar measure on the Grassmannian as a homogenous space is probably way more elegant, but I don't know enough about it to make it into a satisfactory answer.

I'll drop $\sigma$-algebras throughout. It's always either the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, since we're mostly talking about topological spaces, or the $\sigma$-algebra induced by a map.

### Method 1: Span of Random Basis

We'll choose $k$ independent unit vectors at random and take their span. So we'll take a $\tilde S_k:=\underbrace{S^{d-1}\times\dots\times S^{d-1}}_{k\textrm{ times}}$ valued random variable $X=(X_1,\dots,X_k)$. Then the map $\operatorname{span}(X)$ is a random variable with values in the set $\operatorname{Sub}(d)$ of subspaces of $\mathbb R^d$. We'll have to do some technical work to make the vectors independent so $\operatorname{span}(X)$ only takes values in the set of $k$-dimensional subspaces, i.e., the Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)$.

Obviously, $\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)\subseteq\operatorname{Sub}(d)$. Consider the map $\operatorname{span}:\tilde S_k\to\operatorname{Sub}(d)$. The preimage of $\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)$ under this map is exactly the set of independent $k$-tuples in $\tilde S_k$. That's what we need. So we define:

$$S_k:=\operatorname{span}^{-1}(\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)).$$

This is the set of independent $k$-tuples in $\tilde S_k$. Now we're ready to construct random $k$-dimensional subspaces:

Let $X=(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ be an $S_k$ valued random variable. Then $\operatorname{span}(X)$ is a $\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)$ valued random variable. In other words, a random $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^d$.

### Method 2: Sum of Random Subspaces

We'll choose $k$ 1d subspaces (= lines through the origin) and take their sum. So we take an $\tilde L_k:=\underbrace{\mathbb R P^{d-1}\times\dots\times\mathbb R P^{d-1}}_{k\textrm{ times}}$ valued random variable $X=(X_1,\dots,X_k)$, and then $$\operatorname{sum}(X_1,\dots, X_k):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^k X_n=\operatorname{span}(X_1,\dots, X_k)$$ is a random variable with values in $\operatorname{Sub}(d)$. We take the same technical steps to ensure that $\operatorname{sum}$ only takes on values in $\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)$: define

$$L_k:=\operatorname{sum}^{-1}(\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)).$$

This is essentially the set of all $k$-tuples of 1d-subspaces whose sum is direct. Then take an $L_k$ valued random variable $X=(X_1,\dots, X_k)$ and consider the $\operatorname{Gr}(d,k)$ valued random variable $\operatorname{sum}(X)$. This is a random $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^d$